# Mule munit-runner artefact nit downloaded

Tags: maven, mule, munit

I am experiencing an issue with downloading the munit-runner artefact through maven. For some reason the jar is not downloaded. Not for 1.3.2, 1.3.3 or 1.3.4 
I have cleaned the repository cash and rebuild but nothing seems to help.

The POM file looks according to the MuleSoft documentation.

Te specific error is:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'xxx' is missing required library: '/home/xxxx/.m2/repository/com/mulesoft/munit/munit-runner/1.3.3-SNAPSHOT/munit-runner-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar'   xxx     Build path  Build Path Problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct version to use for MUNIT is this one bellow:

```
 <munit.version>1.3.1</munit.version>
 <mule.munit.support.version>3.8.3</mule.munit.support.version>
```

Comment: Hi Alex this one actually already did it for me :) Thank you!

P.S.: do you have any suggestion on how to add inboundProperties http.request.path in an munit test?

Mule is really awesome!

Comment: MuleMessage message = muleMessageWithPayload(" a payload");
message.setProperty("http.request.path", "a property", PropertyScope.INBOUND);
MuleEvent test = testEvent(message);
  
  MuleEvent resultMuleEvent = runFlow(FLOW_TO_TEST, test);

Comment: Hi Alex, I did vote up but votes from person with less than 15 prestige points are registered but not shown.
So I hope to get to the 15 soon :D Because your solution did work (you should have your experience points increased though). Once again thank you for your great advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below version.

```
<munit.version>1.2.1</munit.version>
<mule.munit.support.version>3.7.4</mule.munit.support.version>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
  <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
  <version>${munit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`
```

if still you are facing the issue then copy the jar from your m2 repository if it is already downloaded otherwise download it from online and manually add it to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

For future references you can find the latests versions of MUnit listed here:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/munit-release-notes

Also, while it's cool for you to play with SNAPSHOT versions please notice that they are just SNAPSHOT thus not stable. 
FYI our SNAPSHOT repositories are periodically clean so you may be pointing to an artifact that's not longer published